# Modify ggplot2 arguments in a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, arguments

I have a function that does some calculations and saves plot into pdf with a structure like this:

```
> myfunction <- function(arg1,arg2,...){

> calc.data <- ... (some calculations)

> ggdf<- melt(calc.data) 
> [... ] # modify ggdf to meet ggplot2 structure requirements

> myplot<-ggplot(ggdf,aes(x,y,colour=A))+geom_bar()+ 
>>theme([some theme modifications]) #default theme arguments

> pdf(...)

> print(myplot)

> dev.off()
> }
```

My question is, what if I want to modify the theme options once I have loaded/sourced the function. Is there a way to add an argument to "myfunction" that will let me modify the "theme()" arguments that I set by default?

Comment: This is a good reason to not do so much inside a single function. Most functions that make ggplots return `ggplot` objects, which can then be modified as desired. By having a single function make a save a plot, you prevent that workflow. I suggest having your function `return(myplot)`, and either leave out the "saving as PDF" code or have it be optional, controlled by a argument.

Comment: @Gregor Do you think that it is good idea to include an argument for the `theme` options and do a `eval(parse(theme.arg))` inside the `...+theme()`. Because I want to run this function in `lapply` or `for` loops.

Comment: If you really want to bake it in the `eval(parse())` is a bad way to do it. Instead, optionally take a list `theme_args` and in your function you use `if (!missing(theme_args)) myplot = myplot + do.call(what = theme, args = them_args)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is amazing that there is so much to learn about R when developing tools. Trying to make others life easier is harder than I thought.